# Strategy.entry if condition is satisfied only in the next bar

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I work on a strategy and i have the following problem.

- vertical red line is the signal candle to enter short
- horizontal dotted line is the desired entry price
- i do not want to enter on the signal bar, so i let process_orders_on_close = false
- i want to enter in trade only in the next bar if price entry stop price is triggered there, do not want to wait for price to rally ex 5 bars then hit my entry

[example on chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxCMF.jpg)

```
//@version=5
strategy("str demo", "str demo", overlay=true)

var float desired_entry_price = 0.0
var float entry_low = 0.0
var float entry_high = 0.0
var float c_entry_range = 0.0
var float position_avg_price = 0.0

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))

if shortCondition and strategy.position_size == 0
    line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close + 1, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color=color.new(color.red, 70)  ) //vertical line
 
if shortCondition and strategy.position_size == 0
    entry_low  := low
    entry_high := high
    c_entry_range := entry_high - entry_low
    desired_entry_price := entry_low - 10 * syminfo.mintick
    
    strategy.entry("es", strategy.short, qty = 10, stop = desired_entry_price )

position_avg_price := strategy.position_avg_price
s_sl1 = entry_high
s_tp1 = entry_low - (c_entry_range * 2.5)

plot(desired_entry_price, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.new(color.red, 0) )

if strategy.position_size < 0  
    strategy.exit("x1", "es", qty_percent = 100, limit = s_tp1, stop = s_sl1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel pending orders if the condition is met and there was no entry on the next bar.
Just use `strategy.cancel()` or `strategy.cancel_all()` function. Add this to the end of your script:

```
if shortCondition[1] and strategy.position_size == 0 
    strategy.cancel_all()
```